# Stopping jQuery affecting children

Tags: jquery

I am making a simple dropdown on click menu and can't seem to work out how to stop the script affecting the child links.

```
$('#sidebarLeft li.page_item').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).children().length > 0 ) {
        $('a', this).attr('href','#');
    }
});
```

The  parent is correctly having it's link wiped however it won't stop at the parent. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, Dan

### EDIT

This is to work with Wordpress `wp_list_pages()`, which will display all the post categories with their relevant permalinks.

The idea is to prevent the parent permalinks from having any `href` and so the best way I could think of was to swap the permalink with a '#'

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VNZRm/)

Comment: Can you show the HTML you're using? Better yet, a [reduced test case on jsfiddle would be helpful](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Are you asking how to only run the function on those items with children?

Comment: jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VNZRm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this

```
$('#sidebarLeft li.page_item').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).children('ul.children').length) {
        $(this).children('a').attr('href','#');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VNZRm/2/)

or Better

```
$('#sidebarLeft li.page_item:has(> ul.children)').each(function(){
    $(this).children('a').attr('href','#');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VNZRm/4/)

Comment: Surely that would also wipe the child links?

Comment: This will change the `href` attributes of direct `a` children of `li.page_item` items

Comment: I need ONLY the parent to be changed whilst leaving the children unaffected.

Comment: Give me 2 mins. Thanks in advance by the way

Comment: @Daniel what is the desired o/p

Comment: Better One did it. Thanks Arun!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to alter your selector to only select elements with children. Assuming the relevant children are more `li`s, you'd use:

```
$('#sidebarLeft li.page_item:has(>li)').each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$('#sidebarLeft > li.page_item')
sounds like you might need a more restrictive selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sidebarLeft  li.page_item a').not('ul li ul a').attr('href','#');
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PWNGJ/1/) using background-color to demo.